# What does the owin:AppStartup key in the ASP.Net Identity Samples Web.Config do?

Tags: asp.net-identity-2

I am using the code from the

Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples 2.1.0-alpha1

There's one area of the code that I do not understand and that is the web.config entry below:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="IdentitySample.Startup,WebApplication3" />
```

My code does work without this but I am wondering if I should have something like this.

Can anyone explain to me what this does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this tells OWIN what method to execute on the application start. And `IdentitySample.Startup` method contains code that bootstraps your application.

You can specify this class via an attribute `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartupDemo.TestStartup))]` if you wish.

But this one is `web.config` so it can be changed for different deployment strategies without recompiling the project.

See more details [in documentation](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection).